# Water Evaporation on Earthen Pot

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, everyday-life, evaporation

In earthen pot water molecules lose heat energy, so where is the temperature drop more - on the pot's surface or inside water?

Answer (score 1):

For water to evaporate faster in a pot, heat must flow into the system (of water) from the pot more than the flow of heat from it to the pot. And we know that heat flows from hotter object to colder. Thus the water must remain at a lower temperature.

However, soon an equilibrium will be established between the water and the pot’s inner surface and that’s when further cooling is stopped.