# Why we need earthern pot to keep water cold although open surrounding also allow evaporation!

Tags: thermodynamics, evaporation

Why earthern pot keep water cold?

Many answers say it allow evaporation through pores, but evaporation can happen without pot too, in open surrounding!

So why specifically we need earthern pot?

Comment: You can keep the water in a lake instead of a pot, and it will also stay relatively cool.

Comment: How? Please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earthen pots have pores, and the surface area available for evaporation includes the entire pot's surface and is much greater than an open plastic or metallic container. Moreover, leaving a water container without a lid in the open is not a good idea as it can easily get contaminated.

Comment: So u mean evaporation can also occur from water below at surface of earthen pot (unlike bucket where only surface of water at top can evaporate) but in my book a statement written that tell, water only at top has enough capability to absorb heat and evaporate, so how in pot all i mean entire surface (side of water, bottom  watet all) have capacity to evaporate

Comment: Yes. You effectively give water a larger surface to absorb energy and evaporate. Water that seeps through the walls is also exposed to the outside and able to evaporate. If it were in the bulk, it wouldn't be able to do so.

Comment: So it is not necessary only water at top have capacity to evaporate, it can evaporate from any part of surface if allow to do!

Comment: How long can this evaporation occur?  Because water not much child only a little low that room temperature

Comment: I don't think I understand your statement completely but water will keep on seeping through and evaporating as long as there is water in the earthen pot.

Comment: If the humidity outside is 100%, evaporation will be limited, and so will the chilling effect be.

Comment: @JimClark Yes definitely. That's why earthen pots are not used in extremely humid areas for cooling.

Comment: I think his question is, how much colder than the outside temperature will the water become. Is there a cold temperature limit.

Comment: Ok thank u all so much for giving ur time and knowledge, really helpful

Comment: One more que, what even i kept watter in vessel whose top surface area is same full curved surface area of a pot than also temp in pot is colder than that of vessel, also amt of water is same. According to this vessel with larger top surface area should have colder water than that of small one( water amount same)

Comment: Once again, you are ignoring the fact that you'll need to keep the container open which would contaminate it and the design  won't be very practical. But if we ignore that, then the surface area available for evaporation will be the same and the temperature of the water in the two containers should be the same.

Comment: But i think water in that vessel would not be evenly cool because water from top only evaporate unlike overall surface in pot

Comment: Also related (although it is not a duplicate): https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/551632/water-evaporation-on-earthen-pot?rq=1

Comment: @giorgioP i cannt understand it much, pls explain

Comment: @Mechanic, can u clear some of my doubts related to this topic?

Comment: ok. What are your doubts exactly?

Comment: See 1. Does water in eathern pot take heat from pot surface or from water inside, because i read many answer they were different, some say evaporation hapoen from pot surface so leaving pot cold and thus heeat from water inside trabfer to pot and proces continue leaving water cold.                                            
  2. Ok! Evaporation occur but why can't water take heat from surrounding or sunlight(if pot is in open) rather than pot surface or even any surface like sweat take heat from skin, why not atmosphere?

Comment: The conductive heat transfer from the surface is a lot more than the radiative heat transfer from sunlight or the convective heat transfer from the air. That's why the surface cools down.

Comment: Does surface perform evaporation and lower pot temp, thus conduct temp from water high to low temp) and cooling it, or water in pot directly evaporate to cool it down

Comment: The evaporation cools the surface of the pot and the water transfers the heat to the surface of the pot.